# Increase count when new order placed,and decrement when confirmed that order

Tags: php, mysql, e-commerce

I am working on e-commerce project using php(codeigniter,rest api for app)

I am new to e-commerce project so I have requirement like when user place order from mobile app it will save in db

at this time I have to show count of this order in admin panel(may be socket require), and when admin confirm this order count should decrement,

again when new user place order count should increase and it should display in admin panel.

I don't any any idea ,any clue how to built this logic because I never did this concept, kindly suggest me how to to do this using php.

Order table

```
id  product_id  status(0 pending ,1=>completed)  user_id

1    4            0                                1
2    6            1                                1
3    4            0                                5
```

Model query:

```
$this->db>insert('order',array('user_id'=>$id,'product_id'=>1,'status'=>'pending'));
```

Comment: Your question is too broad. Try to come up with a design yourself and then ask about a specific piece you're struggling with. You should be able to do this with a few simple flags and queries.

Comment: @waterloomatt I don't know from where to start after placing order,That's why I asked question like

Comment: OK, then please provide a lot more details about your table structure for your orders and what your models look like. Edit your question with these details instead of replying in these comments. Thx!

Comment: Thx. So does the `status` column indicate that the admin has confirmed the order? If so, does `0,0,0` mean your report should show 3 pending orders? And `0,1,0` would show _2 pending orders_ and _1 confirmed_ order?